# move ctor of class with a constant data member or a reference member

Tags: c++, constructor, c++11, move-semantics

I have some problems understanding when and if the move constructor or move assignment operator are invoked, in particular in the context of a class with constant data member.
Consider the class

```
template<typename T> class A {
  const*T const P ;   // constant data member
  explicit A(const*T p) : P(p) { std::cerr<<" ctor: P="<<P<<'\n'; }
  void test() const { std::cerr" test: P="<<P<<'\n'; }
  // move and copy constructors and assignment operators here
};
```

and the test program

```
class B {
  int X[100];
  A<B> get_a() const { return A<B>(this); }
};

int main() {
  B b;
  A<B> a = b.get_a();   // which operator/ctor is used for '=' here?
  a.test();
}
```

then the results for compilation are different depending on the definitions provided for the move constructor and move assignment operator in class `A<>`, but also on compiler.

**1** without any further declaration in class `A<>` (as above), both g++ (4.7.0) and icpc (13.0.1) compile fine (with option `-std=c++11`) and produce the expected output

```
ctor: P=0x7fffffffd480
test: P=0x7fffffffd480
```

**2** if I declare

```
A&A::operator=(A&&) = delete;
A&A::operator=(const A&) = delete;
```

(which seems sensible in view of the constant data member which must be initialiser-list initialised), but don't provide any further ctor, compilation fails with g++ but is okay wich icpc. If in addition I define either (or both) of

```
A::A(A&&) = default;
A::A(const A&) = default;
```

both compilers are happy. However, g++ is not happy with the combination

```
A::A(A&&) = delete;
A::A(const A&) = default;
```

while icpc is happy.

**3** If I play the same game as in **2**, except that `A::A(A&&) = default;` is replaced by

```
A::A(A&&a) : P(a.P) { std::cerr<<" move ctor: P="<<P<<'\n'; } // never called?
```

(and equivalent for `A::A(const A&)`), the results are completely identical, in particular *no output* is generated from these explicit move and copy ctors.

So which operator is used for `=` in `main()`? (and why is no output produced in the last test?)

And why is this operation allowed here at all, given that `A<>` has a constant data member (the results are identical if I replace the member `const*T const P;` with `const T&R`)?

Finally, in case of the different behaviours of g++ and icpc, which, if any, is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
A<B> a = b.get_a();
```

is not an assignment, but an initialization of `a` from an rvalue. This syntax should fail under C++0x if

1. the move constructor is deleted,
2. the move constructor is declared `explicit`,
3. the copy constructor is deleted and no move constructor is defined,
4. no move constructor is defined and, at the same time the move-assignment is defined or deleted.

Declaration or deletion of the copy assignment operator should not have any influence.

Correction: Different to the copy constructor (which is synthesized even if a user-defined copy assignment operator is provided), the compiler does not synthesize a move constructor if a user-defined move assignment is defined. Hence, the above list should be amended by 4 (which I have done now).

Hence, in my opinion,

- in [1] in the question, both compilers behave correctly,
- in [2]/1, gcc behaves correctly (move assignment prevents generation of move constructor), icpc is wrong,
- in [2]/2, both compilers are correct,
- in [2]/3, gcc is correct, since the move constructor is explicitly deleted; icpc is wrong,
- [3] is a mystery to me. Are you sure you're correct?

Comment: so does this mean that both g++ and icpc made several blunders here? In particular, I'm still puzzled by the lack of any output generated if all relevant operations should write to stderr.

Comment: I'm pretty sure regarding [3]. You can try for yourself, the code is trivial. Btw, Why does the presence of a destructor change the game?

Comment: Because, according to a book by Torsten Will, the presence of a destructor prevents the automatic generation of a move constructor. As it, however, does not prevent the generation of a copy constructor, I am not sure what that means in practice.

Comment: [3] Can be explained by copy elision. The `a` object is constructed in-place.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13567029/neither-copy-nor-move-constructor-called

Comment: I was aware of copy elision, but not that the constructor can even elide them if they have side effects (such as print outs). learned something new today!