# Neither copy nor move constructor called

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, move-constructor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why copy constructor is not called in this case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1758142/why-copy-constructor-is-not-called-in-this-case)
>   [What are copy elision and return value optimization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization)

Can anybody explain to me why the following program yields output "cpy: 0" (at least when compiled with g++ 4.5.2):

```
#include<iostream>

struct A {

    bool cpy;

    A() : cpy (false) {
    }

    A (const A & a) : cpy (true) {
    }

    A (A && a) : cpy (true) {
    };

};

A returnA () { return A (); }

int main() {

    A a ( returnA () );
    std::cerr << "cpy: " << a.cpy << "\n";
}
```

The question arised when I tried to figure out seemingly strange outcome of this example: [move ctor of class with a constant data member or a reference member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13565594/move-ctor-of-class-with-constant-data-member-of-reference-member/13565811#comment18587907_13565811)

Comment: who's the first to find the duplicate? check RVO

Comment: Let's start searching from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1758142/why-copy-constructor-is-not-called-in-this-case :)

Comment: This is **Copy Elision** due to **Return Value Optimization(RVO)** there can be many spices added to this curry but the main ingredient is still RVO and copy elision.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The compiler is free to elide copy and move construction, even if these have side effects, for objects it creates on it own behalf. Temporary objects and return values are often directly constructed on the correct location, eliding copying or moving them. For return values you need to be a bit careful to have the elision kick in, though.

If you want to prevent copy elision, you basically need to have two candidate objects conditionally be returned:

```
bool flag(false);
A f() {
    A a;
    return flag? A(): a;
}
```

Assuming you don't change `flag` this will always create a copy of `a` (unless compilers got smarter since I last tried).

Comment: Thank you. It's hard to google when I don't know what to google for.

Comment: And in one case, elide copies for objects it doesn't create on its own behalf. That case is `Foo f() { Foo a; return a; } ... Foo f = f();`. There is still permitted to be no copy/move, thanks to NRVO. `a` and `f` are variables in different functions, but can still be conflated to a single object by copy elision (along with the temporary which is the return value of `f`).

Comment: Actually this new code will *always* produce a copy, regardless of how smart compilers get, as copy-elision is not allowed in the construction of the return value from `a` (because the return expression contains more than *just* "`a`"). Furthermore, there is a simpler way to stop copy-elision -- `return static_cast<A&&>(A());` (This binds the temporary to a reference, and thus disqualifies it from copy-elision).